# Haskell - Traverse Tree and output to lists

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I have this bit of code, which outputs the nodes after traversing, without any comprehensible order:

```
preorder :: Tree a -> [a]
preorder Empty = []
preorder (Branch x e d) = [x]++(preorder e)++(preorder d)

createTree = Branch 'A' 
                  (Branch 'B'
                          (Branch 'E' Empty Empty) 
                          (Branch 'B' Empty Empty)
                  )
                  (Branch 'A'
                          (Branch 'E' Empty Empty) 
                          (Branch 'A' Empty Empty)
                  )
```

Applying `preorder` to `createTree` outputs :

```
ABEBAEA
```

What i would like to have is a list of all paths going from the root:

```
["ABE","ABB","AAE","AAA"]
```

I have no idea on how to do this, I'm a beginner at Haskell!

Thank you very much for all the help that can be provided.

Comment: I don't see what the `preorder` function has to do with this.

Comment: This is a comprehensible order: prefix order, ther is also infix order and postfix order. But you probably want to display path to every node, so you probably(that's the way I understood your question) need also to use stack to achieve that.

Comment: Note that your example does not clarify what should be the paths of `Branch 'A' Empty (Branch 'B' Empty Empty)`. One might say `["AB"]` or `["A","AB"]`.

Answer (score 4):

This exercise amounts to this:

- What are the paths for the empty tree?
- Let `e` and `d` be trees, each having their paths lists `ep` and `dp`, respectively. How to compute the paths for a tree labelled with `x` and having `e` and `d` as subtrees?

So,

```
paths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
paths Empty = ???
paths (Branch x e d) = ??? -- use x,ep,dp accordingly
       where ep = paths e
             dp = paths d
```

As a extra hint, related to your own example:

```
[ 'A':xs | xs <- ["BE","BB"] ] = [ "ABE" , "ABB" ]
```

Note that `["BE","BB"]` are the paths for your first subtree.

Answer (score 1):

```
paths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
paths  Empty                 = [[]]
paths (Branch x Empty d    ) = map (x:) $ paths d
paths (Branch x e     Empty) = map (x:) $ paths e
paths (Branch x e     d    ) = map (x:) $ paths e ++ paths d
```

I.e. simply prepend `x` to every subpath.

```
createTree = Branch 'A' 
                  (Branch 'B'
                          (Branch 'E' Empty (Branch 'A' Empty Empty)) 
                          (Branch 'B' Empty Empty)
                  )
                  (Branch 'A'
                          (Branch 'E' Empty Empty) 
                          (Branch 'A' Empty Empty)
                  )

main = print $ paths createTree
```

prints `["ABEA","ABB","AAE","AAA"]`